# Display multiple query results in a list box?

Tags: sql, ms-access, listbox, vba, ms-access-2010

My Access form has a list box that displays files the user has selected from an OpenFile dialog box. What I do is copy these list box files into a seperate folder on the network and I save this network path in a tblAttachments table. This table has a one-to-many relationship with my main table - tblIdeaDetails.

I created a query that selects records from the tblAttachments table:

```
SELECT tblAttachments.attachmentPath, tblAttachments.attachmentIdeaID
FROM tblAttachments
WHERE (((tblAttachments.attachmentIdeaID)=[Forms]![frmIdeaSubmission]![ideaID]));
```

My question is, how can I display the results of this query in that same list box when the user is navigating through the records (frmIdeaSubmission in this case, which is bound to the tblIdeaDetails table)? I've tried doing a requery, but I kept getting an "Out of stack" error.

Comment: Are the following all true?: 1.) That `SELECT` query is the Row Source for your list box.  2.) The form includes a bound data control (text box, combo, etc.) named "ideaID".  3.) In the form's On Current event you do `Me.YourListboxName.Requery` If all 3 of those statements are true, I don't understand why you get out of stack error.

Comment: @HansUp - my problem was I didn't have my row source set up correctly. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a lot of information to go on with your question but let me see if I can help anyhow.

My suggestion is to isolate your problem and work it out before incorporating it into your project.  Create a new access database and make a 'demo' of what you are trying to accomplish.

The reason I'm suggesting this is because an 'Out of Stack' error is memory related - could be related to database corruption - a whole myriad of reasons.

Microsoft Support lists a few reasons:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264523(v=vs.60).aspx

As identified by the support page, it can be dependent upon a number of factors that are going to be present throughout the database.

All things being equal, if you have your listbox recordsource bound to the query you indicated - calling the requery method on the listbox object should do the trick.  Changing the record should also force a requery if its bound to a data source.